# I'm in situation where I have to support multiple database in a application without using any ORM just using core jdbc

Tags: java, multiple-databases

I'm in situation where I have to support multiple database in a application without using any ORM just using core jdbc connection. The situation is describe details in the following.

We have legacy code of mysql of our specific product and which is stable, now for the new client requirements we have to give them support for MSSQL, We proposed our CTO to do this by using any ORM but unfortunately he denied it and there are many mysql legacy function have been use there and he is not interested to do this in ORM because he is expert on MSSQL he said that he will able to convert all query which is written on MYSQL now the question is what is the better approach to make the application manageable, sustainable and create in such a manner so that is will able to support many database handling capability.

We are thinking and also need suggestion from you guise.

Comment: Why would you NOT use an ORM. Its ideal in such a case, where the underlying DB details don't matter and you need not convert the queries from *X* type to *Y* type always you consider to change it.

Answer (score 0):

> he is not interested to do this in ORM because he is expert on MSSQL
>   he said that he will able to convert all query which is written on
>   MYSQL

Does that mean whenever someone other than him has an issue going back and forth between sql server and mysql that it's their problem for not being an expert? Doesn't sound fun.

Regardless, you need to somehow validate and test your generated sql queries such that they work for both rdbms, and aren't producing any unintended side effects (try inserting a date into mssql that is before 1753-01-01, and then try it in mysql, for example)

Best of luck to you guys.

Comment: It has been decided we have to do this without ORM so we are looking for solution and suggestion so that many DB can coexist.

Answer (score 0):

Your task could be simplified by using MyBatis. If you are using Spring, you can have a look at Spring JDBC Templates. Both of this approaches give you ability to switch between DB types, while letting you write native SQL. With MyBatis that would be simpler, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you all to give me yours suggestion. I also tried my self with core java solution and want to share.

1. Creating connection object first :
public abstract class ConnectionFactory {
    final static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        DBVendor dbVendor = DBVendor.fromName(Config.MSSQL);

        switch (dbVendor) {
        case MSSQL:
            conn = new MSSQLConnection().getConnection();
            break;

        default:
            conn = new MYSQLConnection().getConnection();
            break;
        }

        return conn;
    }

}

2. Create factory class for the creation of query object and use this query object to appropriate class:


public abstract class QueryFactory {

    public static Query getQuery() {
        DBVendor dbVendor = DBVendor.fromName(Config.MSSQL);
        Query query = null;
        switch (dbVendor) {
        case MSSQL:
            query = new MSSQLQuery();
            break;
                         .
                         .
                         .
        default:
            query = new MYSQLQuer();
            break;
        }
        return query;
    }

}

All query will be separately implemented .

3. Use of query object

public class InfoDao {


    private static Query query = null;

    static {
        synchronized (query) {
            query = QueryFactory.getQuery();    
        }

    }

    public EmployeeInfo getEployeeInfo( int empId) {
        EmployeeInfo employeeInfo = null;
        try {
            DBHandler dbh = DBConnection.newConnection();
            ResultSet rs = dbh.select(query.getInfoSql(empId));

            if(rs.next()) {
                employeeInfo = new EmployeeInfo();

                employeeInfo.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                employeeInfo.setEmployeeType(rs.getString("EMP_TYPE"));
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }

        return employeeInfo;

    }
}

Still need better solution.
```